# Kubernetes Ingress with Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I would like to know how Kubernates Ingress works.

1. Is there an apply order, service and deployment are applied, does ingress come before or after?
2. To test ingress with azure, I created a kubernates service in azure (service and deployment, etc. applied there). In Azure there is the API-Serveraddress under the Kubernate version or under Network (like xyzzy.123.k8s.io ). Can I enter this domain as a host in my Ingress YAML?

like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - xyzzy.123.k8s.io <--- Azure 
  rules:
  - host: xyzzy.123.k8s.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 8080
```

3. where can I see in Azure all my applied ingresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. there is no apply order, kubernetes will create the resources in the order you apply them
2. no, the address you mention is the API address (kubernetes API), you need to create your own DNS name and connect it to the LB IP of the ingress controller
3. the resources you create are inside the cluster and you can see them via the kubectl command